# Can one have pure surface states in a semiconductor without any band bending?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics

I am thinking of this image `http://academic.brooklyn.cuny.edu/physics/tung/Schottky/ele-aff1.jpg`

where there show band bending and the CNL, but those are bulk bands bending towards the neutrality level, why are they not showing pure surface states?

Comment: What would you consider ‘pure surface state’ and where should it appear on a band diagram?

Comment: it would lie in the band gap.. they are localised exclusively on the surface atoms and have dispersion character separate from the bands in the bulk.

Comment: Can you upload the image directly and cite the source? I'm unable to view the link.